# Store and display SQL, PHP, HTML and JS code exactli as it is stored in MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I need to store and display whole JS, PHP and HTML code in MySQL. Is there any way to do it ?

Result for stored PHP should look like

```
<?php echo "something"; ?>
```

but not

```
something
```

for JS

```
<script> document.write('Hallo world.'); </script>
```

but not

```
Hallo, world.
```

HTML

```
<b>Hallo</b>
```

but not

**Hallo**

So it should be displayed exactly as it is stored in MySQL.

Comment: Use whatever function php has to escape html characters.

Comment: Do you currently have code that you are using that does not work?

Comment: i don´t have special code ... just normal SQL inser and normal Select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP `htmlspecialchars` function is designed for this.  Whatever string you pass to it will be converted to the right HTML to display that string.

Comment: Yes - you are right - correct answer.